# Custom exit pop text

Tags: javascript, popup

I know everyone hates these. But I have an exit pop which works how I want it to apart from one thing. I was wondering how I can add a message to the pop up rather than it just saying 'Do you want to leave this site? - Changes you made may not be saved. Here is the code I have. (Sorry for the bad format)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var __redirect_to = 'http://www.example.com';

    var _tags = ['button', 'input', 'a'], _els, _i, _i2;
    for(_i in _tags) {
      _els = document.getElementsByTagName(_tags[_i]);
      for(_i2 in _els) {
        if((_tags[_i] == 'input' && _els[_i2].type != 'button' && _els[_i2].type != 'submit') || _els[_i2].target == '_blank') continue;
        _els[_i2].onclick = function() {window.onbeforeunload = function(){};}
      }
    }
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {};
        setTimeout(function() {
          document.location.href = __redirect_to;
        }, 500);
      },5);
      return '1';
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Is it even possible to do this? Can I change both lines of prompt text? Please let me know how if anybody can help out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: nested beforeunload with a redirect inside of it? You can not redirect the browser in the onbeforeunload.... And brosers removed the ability to set text.

Comment: @epascarello can you think of a better way to write this?

Comment: There is no way to prevent the browser from exiting. so no.

Comment: Thanks @epascarello

Answer (score 2):

You used to be able to set a custom text in the `onbeforeunload` dialog, but in most newer browsers you can't anymore:

> Starting with Firefox 4, Chrome 51, Opera 38 and Safari 9.1, a generic string not under the control of the webpage will be shown instead of the returned string. For example, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." See [bug 588292](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292) and [Chrome Platform Status](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5349061406228480).
>
> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`, and `window.prompt()` methods may be ignored during this event. See the [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#user-prompts) for more details.
>
> (Source: [MDN: `window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload))